# Reading file and converting values "'list' object has no attribute 'find' on"

Tags: python, python-3.x

The main issue is I cannot identify what is causing the code to produce this value. It is supposed to read the values in the text file and then calculate the average confidence of the values. But I've recieved repeated errors. the one here and another which states 'could not convert string into float' if I have it tell me which line it will be the first one.

I'm using Repl.it to run python and it is v3 of it. I've tried doing this on my computer I get similar results, however, it is very hard to read the error so I've moved it there to see better.

```py
# Asks usr input
usrin = input("Enter in file name: ")

# establishes variabls
count = 0

try:
  fmbox = open(usrin, 'r')
  rd = fmbox.readlines() 
  # loops through each line and reads the file
  for line in rd:
      # line that is being read

      fmLen = len(rd)
      srchD = rd.find("X-DSPAM-Confidence: ")

      fmNum = rd[srchD + 1:fmLen] # extracts numeric val
      fltNum = float(fmNum.strip().replace(' ', ''))

      #only increments if there is a value
      if (fltNum > 0.0):
          count += 1
          total = fltNum + count 

  avg = total / count

  print("The average confiedence is: ", avg)
  print("lines w pattern ", count)
```

The return should be the average of the numbers stripped from the file and the count of how many had values above 0.

if you need to view the txt file here it is http://www.pythonlearn.com/code3/mbox.txt

Comment: This is because your `rd` is a `list`. you have to search through your `line` variable.

Comment: Your code snippet is not complete since you do not tell us what `usrin` is. Please read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FarhoodET I tried that out and now I receive 

__could not convert string to float: 'Fromstephen.marquard@uct.ac.zaSatJan509:14:162008' on line:  From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

- you're using string methods like `find()` and `strip()` on the list `rd` instead of parsing the individual line.
- `find()` returns the *lowest* index of the substring if there's a match (since `"X-DSPAM-Confidence: "` seems to occur at the beginning of the line in the text file, it will return index 0), otherwise it returns -1. However, you're not checking the return value (so you're always assuming there's a match), and `rd[srchD + 1:fmLen]` should be `line[srchD + len("X-DSPAM-Confidence: "):fmLen-1]` since you want to extract everything *after* the substring till the end of the line.
- `count` and `total` are not defined, although they might be somewhere else in your code
- with `total = fltNum + count`, you're replacing the total at each iteration with `fltNum + count`... you should be adding `fltNum` to the total every time a match is found

Working implementation:

```
try:
    fmbox = open('mbox.txt', 'r')
    rd = fmbox.readlines() 
    # loops through each line and reads the file
    count = 0
    total = 0.0
    for line in rd:
            # line that is being read
            fmLen = len(line)
            srchD = line.find("X-DSPAM-Confidence: ")

            # only parse the confidence value if there is a match
            if srchD != -1:
                fmNum = line[srchD + len("X-DSPAM-Confidence: "):fmLen-1] # extracts numeric val
                fltNum = float(fmNum.strip().replace(' ', ''))

                #only increment if value if non-zero
                if fltNum > 0.0:
                        count += 1
                        total += fltNum 

    avg = total / count

    print("The average confidence is: ", avg)
    print("lines w pattern ", count)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Output:

```
The average confidence is:  0.8941280467445736
lines w pattern  1797
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@glhr/55679157

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I've never been the best at reading files and searching through them. I always end up confused! I appreciate the help.